# How to use e2e or unit testing with nativescript-vue?

Tags: nativescript, appium, nativescript-vue, detox

How to use e2e or unit testing with nativescript-vue?

Would you please describe a [Getting Started](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md) kind of guide?

Is there any tested **testing method** with nativescript 7 ?

Does [appium](https://appium.io/) or [detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox) really work?

Is it possible to update [ui-tested-nsvue-ap](https://github.com/rigor789/ui-tested-nsvue-app)p somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for unit testing, [How to set up unit testing in NativeScript Vue](https://www.bryanleetc.com/how-to-set-up-unit-testing-in-nativescript-vue/)

Foe e2e take a look on this, [NativeScript-Vue UI tests](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue-ui-tests)

Didn't try this repository yet but considering who the contributors are it seems promising.